# Regex to check if first character is "."

Tags: regex

How to write regex to match if only first character is `.` ?

I'v been trying this:

```
hide_file={.*}
```

But unfortunately, it will find all files that has `.` in it.
For example:

```
/home/user
  .bashrc
  .bash_history
  some_text.csv
  foo.json
```

In this example I would like this regex to affect only first two files.

#### P.S

That's the requirement:

```
Supported regex syntax is any number of *, ? and unnested {,} operators. Regex matching is only supported on the last component of a path, e.g. a/b/? is supported but a/?/c is not. Example: deny_file={*.mp3,*.mov,.private}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use

```
^\s*?\..*$
```

See http://regex101.com/r/oW1xP3 for a live demo

If you are sure there are no whitespaces in front of your input remove the `\s*?`

Comment: Seems like it should be `\s*?` not `+`, since there may-or-may-not-be spaces, no?

Comment: @chill0r hi, I just tried your regex and found some restrictions at the place where I'm using it (`vsftpd` server). I updated an answer, could you please help with this requirements?

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to anchor `^` the regex to the beginning of the string.

`^\.` will match any string that begins with a period.  **Note: ** you will need to escape this regex appropriately for your programming language.

```
hide_file={^\.}
```